# onCallStateChanged() method failed to give incomingNumber

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have created a call recording application and wants to save the recorded audio file with the incomingNumber which is the argument of onCallStateChanged() method but it's not providing any incomingNumber. What's going wrong.

I'm Using Android Studio and HTC Desire C as testing device.

Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
@Override
    public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        Log.d("MyLogs", "state:" + state + " incomingNumber:" + incomingNumber); //incomingNumber is empty.

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the docs: "incoming call phone number. If application does not have READ_PHONE_STATE permission, an empty string will be passed as an argument." So do you have declared the permission right in your manifest? See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: @and_dev Yes all the required permissions are in manifest!

Comment: I just observed one thing that the incomingNumber at my BroadcastReceiver but still it's not showing incommingNumber on `onCallStateChanged(state,string)` method